# Prevent script from running on mouseover of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

and thanks in advance for any help.

I have the simple script below to perform a click or the right arrow of a slider (to show the next slide):

```
<script>
        // Simulate click function
        function clickButton() {
            document.querySelector('.slick-next').click();
        }
  
        // Simulate a click every second
        setInterval(clickButton, 4000);
</script>
```

The problem is that I must prevent the slider from advancing when the mouse is over the slider.
My slider has the class ".product-carousel" and the right arrow has the class ".slick-next".

In plain English I'm looking for something like:

```
 If the mouse is over the slider {
 do nothing
 }
 else {
 click on the right arrow every 4 seconds.
 }
```

And then, too make things even more complicated, I need to change the speed in larger screens (because the slider shows 4 pictures on desktops and users need more time to see them all), so, on top of the mouseover problem I have the screen resolution problem.

Again, in plain English this is my goal:

```
 If the mouse (or finger) is over the slider {
 do nothing
 }
 else {
   if resolution is smaller than or equal to 1024px {
     click on the right arrow every 4 seconds.
   }
   else {
     click on the right arrow every 7 seconds.
   }
 }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the code that moves the slider on mouse over? Are you working with an existing carousel library?

Comment: I have to stick with the slider implemented by the theme. I cannot use a 3rd-party slider because the slider must query ads published by users, and external sliders cannot query the ads, just products, posts or pictures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide this problem into different pieces so we can come up with a structured solution

**Detect Hover on carousel**

```
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');

carousel.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
  console.log('Mouse hovering...');
});

carousel.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
  console.log('Mouse not hovering...');
});
```

**Automatically click through carousel**

```
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.slick-next');

const nextButtonInterval = setInterval(() => nextButton.click(), 4000);
```

**Stopping automatic cycling**

```
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.slick-next');

const nextButtonInterval = setInterval(() => nextButton.click(), 4000);
clearInterval(nextButtonInterval);
```

**Adding the three of them together**

```
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.slick-next');
const cycleTime = 4000;

const startAutomaticCycling = (cycleTime) => {
  return setInterval(() => nextButton.click(), cycleTime);
};

let nextButtonInterval = startAutomaticCycling(cycleTime);

carousel.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
  clearInterval(nextButtonInterval);
});

carousel.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
  nextButtonInterval = startAutomaticCycling(cycleTime);
});
```

Here's a working example of what was explained above.
Please notice how the button animates and logs a `click` but as soon as you hover the carousel it stops.

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.slick-next');
const cycleTime = 4000;

const emulateClickVisually = () => {
  nextButton.blur();
  nextButton.focus();
  setTimeout(() => nextButton.blur(), 400);
  nextButton.click();
  console.log('Button clicked...')
};


const startAutomaticCycling = (cycleTime) => {
  return setInterval(emulateClickVisually, cycleTime);
};

let nextButtonInterval = startAutomaticCycling(cycleTime);

carousel.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
  clearInterval(nextButtonInterval);
});

carousel.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
  nextButtonInterval = startAutomaticCycling(cycleTime);
});
```

```css
.slick-next { 
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.slick-next:active,
.slick-next:focus {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.carousel {
  padding: 250px 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="slick-next">Next</button>
  <div class="carousel">
    <h1>Carousel</h1>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed approach to this. Unfortunately it's not working for me. I've changed the class ".carousel" to ".product--carousel" to match my HTML but it doesn't work.
And I'm getting an error on Chrome Dev Tools related to the "click()" portion of the code. The error is as follows:

Comment: (pressed enter instead of shift+enter and the comment was posted before finishing it...)

The error is as follows:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')

Comment: Seems like the `nextButton` is not being found by the `querySelector` function. Can you confirm?

Comment: It might be. I've been trying so many approaches that I'm kind of lost already... In any case the original script to perform a click every 4 seconds works so my best hope is to simply prevent the click from happening when the mouse is over the slider. I'm looking for a slight modification of the script from my original question.
Sincere thanks for your effort. :-)

Comment: Great to hear that. If you think it helps, I could create a quick prototype that better explains the approach, that way you can have an inspiration of how it could work

Comment: That would be great. Any help implementing a single solutions that prevents the click on mouseover and that allows me to change the speed of the click on smaller screens would be awesome.

Comment: I've just added the snippet and it's working pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

**All of the desires you are describing are native functions of the Slick slider.**

For example: the `pauseOnHover` can be used to stop a slider from sliding when hovered.

Another example is the support for different settings at different breakpoints:

```
$('.foo').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        centerMode: false,
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

And even the automatic sliding is a native setting: `autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000`.

Please have a look at the official [Slick documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

**Edit:** you can also change settings AFTER initializing the Slick slider, thus you can set your desired settings in an external script. You can do so by setting `slickSetOption` on the previously initialized Slick element.

In your case you would use something along the lines of the following code:

```
$('.foo').slick('slickSetOption', {
   centerMode: true,
   slidesToScroll: 1
}, true); // set to true if the changed options is a UI update
```

You can use all settings you would use when normally initializing a Slick slider. Just make sure you run the script AFTER the Slick slider has been initalized and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I have to stick with the slider implemented by the theme. I cannot use a 3rd-party slider because the slider must query ads published by users, and external sliders cannot query the ads, just products, posts or pictures...

Comment: Your code suggests that your theme implements the Slick slider.

Comment: Yes it does suggest that. But even if so it won't be a good idea to to change theme files because I would loose the changes after an update.
I'm simply creating a small script to perform a click (not to slide) on the slider's right arrow. And I need the click to be prevented when the mouse is over the slider

Comment: @NunoMiguel please check the updated version of my answer. It includes the `slickSetOption` setting that can be used after initializing a Slick slider. This should be the right solution for you.